# Adding a C++ library in iOS project won't compile properly

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

In my iOS project I need to use a C++ library consisting in some header (.h) files and a .a library file (I don't have any actual source code).

In my Obj-c code I imported the .h header that I need, however Xcode doesn't seem to understand it has to interpret the header as c++, in fact it returns an endless list of issues including "not found" errors on inclusions like theese:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

and other c++ language-specific syntax.
Unfortunately changing the .h extension to .hpp doesn't solve the issue, and neither setting the file type to "C++ Header" in the Xcode file inspector does.

Any suggestion? Is there any flag I need to set somewhere to manually indicate to use g++ on the library files? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import C++ headers only in Objective-C++ files, change your objc-file extension to `.mm`.

Comment: Hi, I have already tried that: unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue either.

Comment: Solved this. I was importing the c++ header in my obj-c header. Moved the import statement inside the .mm source file and everything compiled properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change your objectiveC-file extension from .m to .mm
Clean the project 
then there you go

happy coding